# How to get a single relationship data between 2 nodes having multiple reltionship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 nodes and I am storing 2 relationships between same nodes having a different property

```
MATCH (n)-[rel:HAS_PAY_GROUP_AREA]-(m)
```

Here `rel` has amount and state. State is DRAFT/PUBLISHED and at a same time the state may be both with a published value and with a draft value, I want to filter if the Draft relationship exist then it will out else give the published(if exist as well).

Any idea or suggestion 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.Can you provide a sample data set and the expected result? Thanks.

Comment: There is the data stored in relationship like 
{
  "state": "DRAFT",   
  "Amount": "8"
},{
  "state": "PUBLISHED",   
  "Amount": "80"
} the relationship(rek in my case) stores state of the relationship , I want to filter the data if state draft is available between the nodes then skip this published

Comment: create (n:TEST{name: 1})
create (n2:TEST2{name: 3})
create(n)-[r1:HAS_PAY_GROUP_AREA]->(n2) set r1.state='DRAFT'
create(n)-[r2:HAS_PAY_GROUP_AREA]->(n2) set r2.state='PUBLISHED'
return n,n2,r1,r2  now how to get n,n2 resultset with draft relationship if(exist)otherwise it will give published one

Comment: I answered your question. Please, let me know if my answer has solved your issue. And also, if the answer has solved your issue, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: not completely , I am adding this in my scenario and up-vote once done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
match (:TEST{name: 1})-[r1:HAS_PAY_GROUP_AREA]->(:TEST2{name: 3})
with r1 order
by r1.state = 'DRAFT' desc
limit 1
return r1
```

I'm getting all relationships between `n` and `n2` nodes. These relationships are ordered by the expression `r1.state = 'DRAFT'` in descending order. This way the relationships where the expression is true come first in the order. Also, I'm limiting to 1. When no relationship with `r1.state = 'DRAFT'` exists the published one is returned.